# VIM: How to move cursor down to last line of text in a block without changing column?

Tags: vim

Often times I want to edit every line in a block of text the same way, so I would type

`<C-V>}`

This achieves selecting the whole block, but unfortunately is goes one line past the last line of the block and changes the cursor position. So then I have to press k followed by what ever sequence corrects the cursor position. Often I find it's just easier to press `j` until I'm on the last line. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Example: I want to change the following from

```
std::cerr << "abc::blah " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "def::text " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "ggg::something " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "xyz::else " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "qrs::random " << std::endl;
```

to:

```
std::cerr << "Foo::blah " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Foo::text " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Foo::something " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Foo::else " << std::endl;
std::cerr << "Foo::random " << std::endl;
```

So I find myself putting the cursor on the first **a** on line one and then I would type `<C-V>jjjjecFoo<ESC>`

Is there a way to move the cursor down to the end of the block without going past it or changing the column, i.e. something equivalent to pressing j until the last line of the block?

Comment: The plugin https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-vertical-move seems to do what you want (I haven't tried it out personally though). Can't think of a way to do this without a plugin right now unfortunately (without using/counting line numbers, which is pretty much your solution but using `4j` instead of `jjjj`).

Comment: Yes, That looks like what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's nothing built-in, but you can define a custom mapping (`g}` seems appropriate), as shown in [this answer on vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20784/8892):

```
vnoremap <silent> g} :<C-U>call cursor(line("'}")-1,col("'>"))<CR>`<1v``
```

The only problem I've found with this is that it doesn't work when the last line of the paragraph is also the last line of the buffer, but then an additional `j` will fix the selection.

Comment: `it doesn't work when the last line of the paragraph is also the last line of the buffer` As it was mentioned in my answer, to address this case one needs: `:<C-U>call cursor(line("'}")-empty(getline(line("'}"))),col("'>"))<CR>`<1v```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom [`:help :map-operator`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-operator) that just uses the line number of the move, but keeps the current column:

```
"<Leader>gl{motion} Jump to the line at the end of {motion}; keep the
"           current column.
function! s:SetCursor( lnum, virtcol )
    call cursor(a:lnum, 0)
    execute 'normal!' a:virtcol . '|'
endfunction
function! OnlyLineJumpOperator( type ) abort
    call s:SetCursor(line("']"), virtcol('.'))
endfunction
function! OnlyLineJumpVisual( type ) abort
    normal! gv
    call OnlyLineJumpOperator(a:type)
endfunction
function! s:OnlyOneCoordinateJumpExpression( what, mode ) abort
    let &opfunc = printf('Only%sJump%s', a:what, a:mode)
    return (a:mode ==# 'Visual' ? "\<C-\>\<C-n>" : '') . 'g@'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>gl     <SID>OnlyOneCoordinateJumpExpression('Line', 'Operator')
xnoremap <expr> <Leader>gl     <SID>OnlyOneCoordinateJumpExpression('Line', 'Visual')
```

With this, your use case would become `<C-v><Leader>gl}ecFoo<Esc>`.

#### Bonus

For completeness, you can also add the opposite mappings (that keep the line and only change the column):

```
"<Leader>g|{motion} Jump to the column at the end of {motion}; keep the
"           current line.
function! OnlyColumnJumpOperator( type ) abort
    execute 'normal!' virtcol("']") . '|'
endfunction
function! OnlyColumnJumpVisual( type ) abort
    normal! gv
    call OnlyColumnJumpOperator(a:type)
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>g<Bar> <SID>OnlyOneCoordinateJumpExpression('Column', 'Operator')
xnoremap <expr> <Leader>g<Bar> <SID>OnlyOneCoordinateJumpExpression('Column', 'Visual')
```